# Cloud9 (rails setup) - url doesn't change along with actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9

I'm trying to build a blog using rails in c9 ubuntu setup. While I was optimizing routes, I realized that my url in browser does not change along with my actions, though everything works just fine.

[image]

The url that can be seen in the browser is actually set to display all the blogs' posts, and it does, but when I try to click on only one (in this case 'My Blog Post 1') it performs the action, but url remains the same.

However, if I type the correct url manually, it also works.

[image]

Everything is working, but my url doesn't change automatically, but I have to do it manually. In this stage I can handle that, but I'm afraid I'll have problems with that later on. This is my first time that I use cloud9 environment. 
Controller:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /blogs
  # GET /blogs.json
  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  # GET /blogs/1
  # GET /blogs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /blogs/new
  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  # GET /blogs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /blogs
  # POST /blogs.json
  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.save
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /blogs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /blogs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.update(blog_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /blogs/1
  # DELETE /blogs/1.json
  def destroy
    @blog.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to blogs_url, notice: 'Blog was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :portofolioos, except: [:show]
  get 'portofolioo/:id', to: 'portofolioos#show', as: 'portofolioo_show'

  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'contact', to: 'pages#contact'

  resources :blogs

  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

View just has a form. It's pretty much scaffold, I only changed show page to display id in url and added friendly_id gem, but none of it is displayed in url, but it works just fine.

```
  <p><%= link_to portofolio_item.title, portofolioo_show_path(portofolio_item) %></p>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that is used to generate the link for an individual blog post?

Comment: I post the code

Comment: I'm interested in the code that generates the link that points to the individual blog post.

Comment: This is used for portofolio, to display id of the selected one.

Comment: The added line is in index file